# RabbitMQ/AMQP Exchange Routing Strategy

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a scenario where publishers need to send messages to a known exchange (they won't know the downstream queues directly). Most of the messages should be delivered to every bound queue (like a fanout), but some need to be delivered only to a specific bound queue. I'd like to avoid multiple exchanges as well as multiple queue bonds.

My current solution uses header routing, where a message has one of two headers, identify it as "global" or "specific to a particular sub", where the downstream queues are bound on a match-any to both of those headers. I think this will work, but I feel like there should be a simpler solution.

I tried to find an exchange plugin that would "fanout all messages except specific ones", but I couldn't find such a plugin. Outside of that, any ideas on how to implement such a routing strategy?

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvoted, but I would think a topic exchange would be the best option for this.

Comment: @mshindal - Not sure why either; it seems like a reasonable question for a legitimate use-case (and I've done tons of research). With regard to your suggestion, I'm not sure how to make this work with a topic exchange, unless I bind two queues for each client (one for "all messages" and one for "specific messages"). Is two queues what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, my original solution using a "headers" exchange with queues bound using "match any" is the only one I could find, short of writing a new exchange plugin. It does work and so far seems reasonably fast (at least not measurably slower than a typical "topic" exchange--which I could find no way to apply in this scenario).

From my research on this topic, the ideal solution would be a "topic" exchange with the ability to use a RegEx or at least some form of "or-logic". I did find some information that implied that a RegEx was considered but decided against (in favor of the "dotted notation" topic format) because the latter was faster, specifically because the use a a RegEx would require that every binding be evaluated on each new message (i.e. there was no way to construct a "search shortcut").

For now, my "match-any headers exchange" solution will serve my purposes, but in the future, a "topic" exchange that allowed "or-logic" might be worth exploring. It would allow multiple topic patterns to be achieved with single-binding, without the overhead of a RegEx. But I have no experience with Erlang, nor the time to learn enough of it to write the necessary plugin. Please contact me if anyone is interested in collaborating on this.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe really sounds like exchange-to-exchange binding though, as rich routing is actually one of RMQ's strengths.

You could create the entry exchange that would point to either the fanout (for generic case) or topic/direct one (for the special one), and leave all routing to RMQ. The `entry-exchange` could be a header exchange or a direct one, depending on what you want to put in headers:

```
entry-exchange -----> fanout-exchange ---*---> multiple-fanout queues
               \
                \---> the special exchange --> queue-for-special-usecase
```

Comment: Yes, I had taken a hard look at using bound exchanges, but all solutions I found (including what I believe you're suggesting) would require the clients to be bound to two different queues (one for fanout and one for direct). This is something I was specifically trying to avoid, as there will be a large number of clients, so I didn't want to multiply that by 2X.